# Get unencrypted secret key from the encrpyted one in a programmatic way

Tags: tezos-client, cryptography, encrypted

I developed a small script to generate a new tezos account, result has this form: ->

```
{ sk:
   'edskReYTc3xorfemyNAcrYb6Sz8Wgj6e1PfevpZ6uysf4KXWBNxXcoLA4KBtZp7hmUCy6V3bhtWZRMSuya5DgXA1TU2JXYeDmG',
  pk: 'edpktnRinzUJFSfkvL9VC7Mfcb5PFDtKeXhZmjEcBGfKnJc9PKZWXn',
  pkh: 'tz1Ub34SJF9DsUvsmqQqnrJ7gw6SreCg2Pue' 
}
```

What I get for the secret key is `ed25519 secret key` with a length of 98, I want to unencrypt it to get `ed25519 seed` with a length of 54, just like the secret key displayed when entring `./tezos-client show address tz1..... --show-secret` ->

```
Hash: tz1MwakuLuEmR9X96uT9rfQyc62S3BnZNvi6
Public Key: edpktirtvUD2T8MyZYKLfAFNVYrtTtFhUJCAr1uWsKXBHjnHvyT68N
Secret Key: unencrypted:edsk4QPXFBLsi5Pmx5PY6PnKDSB2GWrBw913qrRm5LGtJiXDVatFNC
```

Is it possible programmatically to pass from the first secret key form (length == 98) to the second (length == 54)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using pytezos that would be:

```
>>> from pytezos import Key
... Key.from_encoded_key('edskReYTc3xorfemyNAcrYb6Sz8Wgj6e1PfevpZ6uysf4KXWBNxXcoLA4KBtZp7hmUCy6V3bhtWZRMSuya5DgXA1TU2JXYeDmG').secret_key()
<<< 'edsk2pR4GssrHRPDFBci4wkLGAH97HcwmLAWMEGWh6D9zyTUvbQb1p'
```

Under the hood:

1. Base58 decode (with checksum)
2. Cut first 4 bytes
3. That's ed25519 secret key (64 bytes)
4. Using crypto_sign_sk_to_seed from libsodium (extract the first 32 bytes from the secret key)
5. Got 32 bytes long seed
6. Adding 4 bytes prefix (0x0d0f3a07)
7. Base58 encode with checksum

Comment: Thank you, it works with pytezos, I tried to implement the "under the hood" that you mentioned but libsodium.js doesn't have the **crypto_sign_sk_to_seed** function, do you know an alternative in JS?

Comment: Try crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_seed

Comment: Doesn't exist also :/, I searched in all the libsodium.js for a function xxx_to_seed and nothing there.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-framework-o5mbt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I didn't try with **libsodium-wrappers-sumo**, it finally works, this is how for everyone else in the future: 



**b58encode(sodium_sumo.crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_seed(b58decode(sk, prefix.edsk)), prefix.edsk2);**

Comment: I think that it might be useful to explain what does `crypto_sign_sk_to_seed` do: it extracts the first 32 bytes from the secret key. Actually, the secret key is a concatenation of the seed and the public key.